# Uncaught Error: Class 'NumberFormatter' not found

Tags: php

I know lots of people asked this question before, and I read a lot of them but none of them works for me for now, here is what I got:

1. I'm running PHP 7.4.24(TS, VC15 x64) on Windows NT ** 10.0 build
   19043 (Windows 10) AMD64 with Apache/2.4.51 (Win64) PHP/7.4.24,
   The compiler is Visual C++ 2017.
2. Checked the extension_dir already (correct)
3. Checked the files php_intl.dll and php_curl.dll in the folder already (exist)
4. Checked the loaded modules with php -m in the command line (loaded)
5. Uncommented "extension=intl" in php.ini
6. Stop and start the service in the command line many times
7. Restart the computer many times.

After all of these attempts, it still doesn't work.
I checked the log file, it shows 2 warnings:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: D:\PHP\php_program\ext\curl (The specified module could not be found.), D:\PHP\php_program\ext\php_curl.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: D:\PHP\php_program\ext\intl (The specified module could not be found.), D:\PHP\php_program\ext\php_intl.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

But the other DLLs like php_mbstring.dll, php_fileinfo.dll work just fine, only these two aren't.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Sir, this may be not relevant but can I suggest you to move on docker?

Comment: @ShamirImtiaz Thanks, but not familiar with Docker, maybe give it a try next time I re-install the Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I were Googling this for days, occasionally I saw [this article](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/235132/php-extension-intl-missing-for-magento-v-2-2-25) posted by Rohan Hapani this morning and he said:

> Copy all the files that look like icu*.dll and paste them into the apache bin directory.

I give it a try, after restarting the service, it worked!

I have no idea why, but it solved my problem, THANK YOU!

If someone knows why this way works, please enlighten me with your instructions